# C++ Application crashes when QTWidgets is included

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, conan, qt6

I am using conan to install qt, and cmake to build my application. My platform is Windows, and my compiler is MSVC 16. I am using cmake and conan because I do not wish to rely on QT's build system (qmake) and QT's way of installing the package, since I wish other devs can directly clone my repository and use cmake+conan to install dependencies and build my application.

My `conanfile.txt` is as follows:

```
[requires]
qt/6.4.1

[generators]
cmake_find_package
cmake_paths

[options]
qt:shared=True
qt:opengl=dynamic
```

I create a directory called `build` and inside that directory I do:

```
conan install .. -s build_type=Debug
```

Then from my project root directory I do

```
cmake -Bbuild

cd build

cmake --build . -j 12 --target helloworld --config Debug
```

Contents of root `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(helloworld VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan_paths.cmake)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
qt_standard_project_setup()

add_executable(helloworld
    src/main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(helloworld PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets)
```

Contents of `src/main.cpp`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the executable, nothing is printed to stdout, and it exits with the exit code `-1073741515`

If I comment out `#include <QtWidgets>`, and rebuild my executable, then it runs as expected.

EDIT:

It seems this is due to dll not found errors. So I added the following line to my `conanfile.txt` so that the DLL files are copied to the correct location

```
[imports]
bin, *.dll -> ./Debug
```

Now all the DLL files are copied, and when I add a simple QApplication with a QPushButton, and run the the program, I get the following error:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

EDITv2:

Now I ran into this page: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows-deployment.html, and ran `windeployqt.exe` located in the installation location of qt in the conan cache, which copied over some DLLs, presumably the windows plugin dll over into the exe directory

Now my application runs fine.
But I cannot automate this process, because the location of `windeployqt.exe` is in a folder inside the conan cache, and it has a random name like `7065d7`, which I only figured out by manual inspection.

Comment: I guess you are missing some `*.dll`s. Try running app from file explorer(by double clicking app icon). If I am correct, it will pop up missing `dll`s

Comment: In support of @Deumaudit 's comment, `-1073741515` is the decimal representation of `0xc0000135`, which is the code for Windows error "unable to locate component".

Comment: I added the following line to my conanfile.txt:
bin, *.dll -> ./Debug

Now all the DLL files are copied but I run into this issue:
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Comment: You might want to use the ``imports`` feature to automate the copy of dlls and exes from the cache to user space (imports in 1.X, deployers in 2.0). If you want further information, it is possible to submit questions too to the official repo in Github: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues

Comment: Here's a description of the files copied (doesn't seem to be well documented though): https://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows ; If you simply need to be able to run the app from Visual Studio, I recommend just adding the location of the dlls to the path for the debugger, which hopefully has the dynamically loaded stuff at the appropriate paths relative to the linked dlls: `set_target_properties(helloworld PROPERTIES VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT "PATH=$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:Qt6::Core>;$ENV{PATH}")`